# Puppet "onlyif" attribute cannot find not(!) operator

Tags: node.js, puppet, redhat

I am trying to figure out if Node package PM2 is installed in the path and executable or not with the following puppet code.

```
 exec { "create symbolic link for pm2":
    cwd => "${pm2_link_dir}",
    path => ['/usr/bin','/bin','/usr/sbin','/sbin'],
    onlyif => "! which node &> /dev/null",
    command => "ln -s ../lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 pm2"
}
```

It is telling me cannot find command "!". Is this the right way to find out if some program is installed and executable?? And why puppet cannot understand The not operator?? I am working on Redhat master and slave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And why puppet cannot understand The not operator?

The `!` operator is provided by the shell; it is not a command.  You are using `Exec`'s default provider (`posix`) which runs your commands directly rather than via a shell.  (Or so it is documented to do.  It has recently come to light that sometimes the `posix` provider runs commands via the shell, in apparent contradiction of its docs.)

It is anyway a bit silly to use `!` in an `Exec`'s `onlyif` attribute, when you could instead drop the `!` and switch to an `unless` attribute instead.  And drop the redirection, which also relies on the shell.

> Is this the right way to find out if some program is installed and executable?

It is usually better to know whether the program *should* be available on the specific target node, and where necessary to ensure that it *is* available.  If you must inquire about node state, then it is usually better to do that via a custom fact.

With that said, I don't think your approach is inherently wrong, though of course it will only look for the requested program in the path you specify in the `Exec`.

Comment: I feel hurt by `It is [...] a bit silly` 